# Software Center error: package indexes are changed

Tags: apt, software-center

I want to download softwares from Ubuntu Software Center, but all the time I am getting this error message:

> The package indexes are currently changed by apt-get.

Please, suggest me what to do.

Comment: @B. Roland, Am having the same problem am using Ubuntu 10.10 and after typing what you instructed earlier am still getting the following error
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
samoei@Samphil1:~$ 
Any solution Roland?

Comment: Edit your question, and add to the description your version of the Ubuntu.

After that, please open a terminal(*Ctrl + Alt + T or Apps > Associates > Terminal*), and type in:`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Does it give any errors? Add them to your question too.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have some other package management application active, like Synaptic, Update Manager, or apt-get in the terminal. Close all such applications and try again.